# MySQL or PostegreSQL for SQL Servers Clusters and high concurrencies?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

some time ago, I created a REST service with very high concurrencies.

Even after SQL Query Optmization, which gave me a bigger time window to think, I am starting to worry about the MySQL DB Server of the service.

The service:

- Multiple Apache Servers, for load balancing, behind an NGINX Reverse-Proxy to deal with the high concurrency
- PHP Opcode cache and Memcached data cache
- One MySQL DB Server with InnoDB Tables schemas on a 64 bit OS
- SQL Queries are stored procs

What problems I could face in a relatively soon time-frame is:

- MySQL DB Server hitting its storage limitation of severals TB of data
- MySQL DB Server hitting its maximum number of concurrent queries for the dedicated CPU/RAM/TCP

What solutions I found and that I am considering:

- MySQL Clusters, but looks like it doesn't support Integrity(FK?)
- Multiple replicated MySQL Servers for load balancing (Cons: Excessive Storage)
- Sharding (Cons: At this point, for me it look pretty complicated to do when I need a solution the soonest possible)
- Switch to PostegreSQL and do more investigation for this specific SQL Server

What would be your suggestions, your best bet, to off-load the MySQL Server? It WILL eventually crash down if I do nothing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much is "very high concurrencies"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution you can take in mind.

you can use pool services which are some queries with the highest need priority. In example, here in stackoverflow most people who want to use their API will ask for the newest questions. so the first person asks for the newest questions they can get it from their db. but as long as it is a high priority query then it will be added to the pool, so anyone who needs it then, they can retrieve it from the pool directly and it will not take so much time as requesting it from the server.

about the pool implementation, it's another criteria to discuss.

another solution yet to have is:
if you have a really large scale of data clusters and you have the select statements increasing a lot, then you can use hdfs from hadoop and apply hadoop on as many servers as you want. this method is used by Facebook, linkedIn, and yahoo.